# adding a new button to the toolbar of reactjs CK editor 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor5

The code is as follows.

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';



render() {
    let selectedDocument = this.state.documentDetails;
    return (
             <div>
                <div>
                    {
                      selectedDocument.html_content &&
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <CKEditor
                            editor={ ClassicEditor }
                            data={selectedDocument.html_content }
                            onInit={ editor => {
                            } }
                            onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
                              const data = editor.getData();
                              let obj = {
                                target: {
                                  name: 'html_content',
                                  value: data
                                }
                              }
                              this.handleChange(obj);
                            } }

                        />
                      </div>
                    }

                  </div>
             </div>
    );
  }
```

Using the above code, the editor is displayed with basic toolbar buttons.

Now I need to add a new button to the toolbar which when clicked a javascript function needs to be called.

I have seen documentation on creating custom plugins, but I am not sure on how to implement this in the react way.

Any ideas on how to implement this?  A sample piece of code would e really helpful.

Answer (score -3):

Find `config.js` in `CKEditor` folder and update `config.extraPlugins` with your plugin like `config.extraPlugins = 'html5video,widget,widgetselection,clipboard,lineutils,videoembed';`
It will display new toolbar or button on CKEditor.

Comment: The question was about CKEditor 5 and you answers is about CKEditor 4. They work very differently.